# How to increase the height of TextField automatically like any chatting app?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter Chat App I am trying to design a chat `TextField`.

[image: image of the design]

I want to increase the height of the **TextField** dynamically when text input goes to new line either from an enter butoon or text overflow from the same line.

I tried different maxLine, minLine combinations, used Expanded in different parent widget level.
Here is my code snippet:

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  late TextEditingController _chatTextController;
  late bool _isEnabled;
  late FocusNode _chatTextFocusNode;
  late double _textFieldHeight;
  ScrollController textFieldScrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _chatTextController = TextEditingController();
    _isEnabled = true;
    _chatTextFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _textFieldHeight = 88.h;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _chatTextController.dispose();
    _chatTextFocusNode.dispose();
    _isEnabled = false;
    textFieldScrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Gap(4.w),
                const CustomBackButton(
                  previousScreen: 'welcome',
                  assetIcon: 'assets/icons/home.png',
                ),
                Gap(4.w),
                Text(
                  'Chat Screen',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22.sp,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: AppColors.titleTextBlack,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: _textFieldHeight,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Divider(
                    height: 0,
                    thickness: 1.h,
                    color: const Color(0xFFBEC9C7),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.h, horizontal: 24.w),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        _chatBox(),
                        Gap(8.w),
                        ChatBoxIconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('*********');
                          },
                          icon: Icons.send_rounded,
                          backgroundColor: AppColors.mainGreen,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _chatBox() {
    return Container(
      height: 56.h,
      width: 308.w,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.w, top: 4.h, bottom: 4.h),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: AppColors.regularTextGrey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.r),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            //width: 242.w,
            child: TextField(
              // expands: true,
              cursorHeight: 18.sp,
              cursorColor: AppColors.mainGreen,
              controller: _chatTextController,
              scrollController: textFieldScrollController,
              focusNode: _chatTextFocusNode,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              onChanged: (value) {
                textFieldScrollController
                    .jumpTo(textFieldScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
              },
              // maxLines: 3,
              minLines: 3,
              maxLines: null,
              //minLines: null,
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 16.sp, color: AppColors.regularTextBlack),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Ask me anything',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.sp, color: AppColors.regularTextGrey),
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ChatBoxIconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('*********');
            },
            icon: CupertinoIcons.mic,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            iconColor: AppColors.regularTextGrey,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate your kind help. Thank you all.

Comment: I think the main problem is that it's wrapped in a `Container` that has `height: 56.h,`. This prevents it from becoming bigger. And also the `_textFieldHeight` is limiting it

Comment: Probably, because of fixed heights like.. `SizedBox(
              height: _textFieldHeight,` and `Container(
      height: 56.h,`

Answer (score 3):

Try below code and set `maxline:null` refer [maxLines](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html)

```
TextFormField(
      maxLines: null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        hintText: "Hint",
        labelText: "Enter Something",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Result: [image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@ravindra-s-patil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13997210/ravindra-s-patil), you can use `maxLines: null` to make a `TextField` auto resize. Although the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html) says it will grow "up to the height of its constraints", the height of the input field can easily overflow in practice:

[image: TextField Height Overflow]

So, instead of `maxLines: null`, you may need both `maxLines` and `minLines`, like this:

```dart
TextField(
  minLines: 1,
  maxLines: 12,
  // ...
)
```

Here `maxLines` is set to a number (greater than 1) to limit the maximum number of lines, and `minLines` is used to specify the initial number of lines.

In this case, the input field will start out with 1 line, and as you enter more text, it will automatically expand up to 12 lines. If the text exceeds the line limit, you can still scroll the text within the box.

As a nice Flutter chat app example, [Flyer](https://flyer.chat/) uses [the same technique](https://github.com/flyerhq/flutter_chat_ui/blob/d559096583b07a20c08785d5acee6fb016460b48/lib/src/widgets/input/input.dart#L198-L199) as we described above.

If you prefer to see it in action, check out my [video explanation](https://youtu.be/mpIcnzaX1s4).