# Change TextFormField height of container child

Tags: flutter, textformfield

```
 bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
          padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
          child: BottomAppBar(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 24,
                vertical: 10,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 16,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 1.5,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      ),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        cursorHeight: 20,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter your text here",
                        ),
                        minLines: 1,
                        maxLines: null,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

This is my code.
But I have some trouble of resizing the textformfield height.

I don't want any height of textformfield.
How can I solve it?

[current issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGYKI.png)

but I want to make like below.
[the one i want to make like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9JG0.png)

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78105875/13997210) answer